# Can't compile SDL project (linker error) with Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition

Tags: sdl, linker-errors, visual-studio-express, visual-c++-2010, visual-c++-2010-express

I am trying to compile a sample SDL project in Visual Studio C++ Express Edition. I have the following linker error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL.lib SDLmain.lib'
```

The problem here is: I added the libraries to the input in the linker section (Additional Dependencies). Why am I having such problem if I added them to the project?

In VC++ Directories I added the libraries directory to the Library Directories value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add the location of those libraries to `Additional Library Directories` on the `Linker/General` page in your project's properties ?

Comment: Now I figured it out. The problem was that the library names were separated by a space, actually it need to be separated by newline.

Comment: Yeah this helped me out quite a bit. I was driving my self crazy trying to understand why I could not open these library files. They just needed a new line...